# Outlook VBA filter issue with multiple variables plus AND operator

Tags: vba, filter, outlook

This filter works. Yes the company name is the persons name and the Full Name is empty. Yes it is silly.

```
Set olContact = Folder.Items.Find("[FullName] = 'empty' AND [Company] = 'Vonda Peters'")
```

This filter works.

```
Set olContact = Folder.Items.Find("[FullName]=" & rs!Contact)
```

I cannot get this filter to work.

```
Set olContact = Folder.Items.Find("[FullName]=" & rs!Contact And "[Company]=" & rs!Company)
```

I'm almost certain it's a syntax issue, but I can't find any filter examples with an AND operator and two variables. I've tried every combination of quotes and ampersand except for the correct one.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I still get a syntax error, but I'll keep working at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your `AND` inside the string. Also, you are missing the `'` around the field values. It should be something like this:

```
Set olContact = Folder.Items.Find( _
      "[FullName]='" & rs!Contact & _
      "' AND [Company]='" & rs!Company & "'")
```